# JMeter - Getting 400 Bad Request

Tags: jmeter, http-status-code-400

In JMeter - I am getting 400 bad request.

I have validated the JSON format, JSON request is correct. But showing error in Request body as
**Error: "Cannot assign " ": "Address.created_by" must be a "User" instance."**

In Header manager- I have included all the correct Content-Type and other headers as well.

Could you please provide a solution for this error?

Comment: `"created_by"` in JSON should be valid `User` Object in your system

Answer (score 0):

This is due server side validation failing and server returning `400 - Bad Request`. Please check the same request object in Postman or SoapUI

Answer (score 0):

JSON request might be correct but JSON request body seems to be incorrect, cross check your request body with API specification documentation i.e. [Swagger UI](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/) it might be the case that API contract has changed and your test is sending the request in the "old" format.

Also [Taurus framework](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation) has a [special tool](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Swagger/) for converting Swagger API definitions into Taurus YAML files which in their turn can be converted into JMeter .jmx scripts